# Converting to JSON-LD from JSON

Tags: java, json, json-ld

I am working on a project which requires us to use an existing service which speaks json-ld. We speak json. I am still working through the http://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/ documentation as well as juggling HOW to convert json > json-ld(and back).

Some questions.. If I supply 2 context's like this..

```
"@context": [
        "http://example/test1/core.jsonld",
        "http://example2/test2/core.jsonld"
    ],
```

How do the key's know which prefix to apply? 
for example

```
(test1 or test2)name : ..
(test1 or test2)date : ..
(test1 or test2)address : ..
```

So far to my understanding of how this works, is that any json can be converted to json ld. We need to supply it a context, so it knows the 'iri' or namespace.

Also, the current example json-ld I am working with also has some key's with no prefix defined, so I imagine there is a default, but there is nothing that shows me what the default is(no @vocab, literally just the two context defined). I imagine the default would be a context, but in this case I have 2.

Correct me if I am wrong but all json can be converted to json-ld and vice versa? I am looking for Java solutions ATM.

a really basic example of what I want

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "A green door",
    "price": 12.50,
}
```

to be

```
{
    @context{
     test : www.example.com/test/core.json-ld
     test2 : www.example.com/test2/core.json-ld
     }
    "id": 1,
    "test:name": "A green door",
    "test2:price": 12.50,
}
```

edit: so here is an example of what the service expects from me

```
{
    "@context": [
        "http://test.net/abcd/contexts/core.jsonld",
        "http://test.net/abcd/contexts/def/4.0/core.jsonld"
    ],

    "startDate": { "@value": "2009-11-21T22:17:10Z", "@type": "xsd:dateTime" },
    "endDate": { "@value": "2005-13-24T22:01:01Z", "@type": "xsd:dateTime" },
    "comment": "my comment",
    "example": [{
      "properties": {
        "name": "test name",
        "description": "test description",
        "geometry": { "objVal": "POINT (127.25 3.243)", "confidence": "abcd-c:MED" },
        "def:width": { "decimalVal" : 50, "units": "abcd-u:meters" },
        "def:length": { "decimalVal" : 75, "units": "abcd-u:meters" },
        "def:height": { "decimalVal" : 200, "units": "abcd-u:meters" },
        "def:status": "operational",
        "def:typeCode": "building"
      },
      "metadata": {
        "@id": "object/123-32132-12321f",
        "type": [ "def:Building" ],
        "def:confidence": { "@id": "abcd-c:HIGH" },
        "def:typeCode": "building"
      }
    }],
    "def:classification": "classified",
    "def:confidence": { "@id": "abcd-c:HIGH" },
    "def:indicator": { "@value": "true", "@type": "xsd:boolean" },
    "def:levelCode": { "@id": "def-cl:FULL" },
    "source": {
      "@id": "remote-store/12321fd-cdsf143221",
      "mediaType": "image/jpeg",
      "startDate": { "@value": "2001-11-11T12:02:02Z", "@type": "xsd:dateTime" },
      "def:classification": "classified",
      "def:producer": "ABC",
      "name": "another name",
      "describedby": "source/123123123-f21321f" 
    }
}
```

my current json of course does not look like this, I can structure it similar but I feel it would be too easy if all I had to do was simply add the @context to my current json and pass it to the service, since it shows me what it expects. It sounds like I might be able to do just that though, and have the service that exists read the json with the annotation as being the same as the example json-ld I provided

Comment: That doesn't seem to be true at all. The description says JSON-LD is "a JSON-based format to serialize Linked Data." It's not a different representation of JSON, it's a representation of LD *in* JSON.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, every JSON-LD document is, by definition, also a valid JSON document.

> How do the key's know which prefix to apply?

The contexts are evaluated in order. This means that term definitions in `test2/core.jsonld` in your example would overwrite the definitions in `test1/core.jsonld`. This is described in more detail in the JSON-LD spec in the section "[Advanced Context Usage](http://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/#advanced-context-usage)".

> So far to my understanding of how this works, is that any json can be converted to json ld. We need to supply it a context, so it knows the 'iri' or namespace.

For *most* documents that's correct. There are a few forms which can't be mapped to sensible JSON-LD by just adding a context.

> Also, the current example json-ld I am working with also has some key's with no prefix defined, so I imagine there is a default, but there is nothing that shows me what the default is(no @vocab, literally just the two context defined). I imagine the default would be a context, but in this case I have 2.

The easiest way to figure out what happens under the hood is to use the [JSON-LD playground](http://json-ld.org/playground/) and expand the document. This gets rid of the context and shows how the processor interprets the data. Terms that aren't mapped to a IRI are ignored (i.e., dropped) when expanding the document.

**Edit:**

> my current json of course does not look like this, I can structure it similar but I feel it would be too easy if all I had to do was simply add the @context to my current json and pass it to the service, since it shows me what it expects.

That would indeed be the easiest solution.

> I am still confused on how the actual conversion from json to ld happens.

JSON-LD is also just JSON. So no magic there.. the simplest thing to do, if you can, is to just bring it into the form the other service expects.

> I am hoping there is some type of library where i just supply it my json and give it a context and it does the conversion for me? is something like this available/possible? My use case is.... I create a json object from the ui, I send this json to my rest service which calls a service, in this service I want to convert it to json ld before calling another service which only understands ld.

That's possible as well but probably more complicated. You would need to call a JSON-LD processor's [compact method](http://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld-api/#the-jsonldprocessor-interface) with the [expandContext](http://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld-api/#the-jsonldoptions-type) option set to a context which maps *your* keys to the right IRIs and the context parameter set to the context(s) the other service expects. If the other service really uses JSON-LD, compacting it to use the same context shouldn't be necessary. Just expanding it by passing expandContext should be enough.

> Lets say the pre-existing service supplies me their context for example www.test.com, what else needs to be done/supplied?

Nothing I guess

Comment: Thank you. I am still confused on how the actual conversion from json to ld happens. I am hoping there is some type of library where i just supply it my json and give it a context and it does the conversion for me? is something like this available/possible? My use case is.... I create a json object from the ui, I send this json to my rest service which calls a service, in this service I want to convert it to json ld before calling another service which only understands ld. Lets say the pre-existing service supplies me their context for example www.test.com, what else needs to be done/supplied?

Comment: Thanks again. So are you saying that if I don't just send them a json-ld by simply adding a @context object, the other solution is that I use a json-ld processor myself and then send them the result of the processed json? Trying to understand what you mean by ' set to a context which maps your keys to the right IRIs and the context parameter set to the context(s) the other service expects. If the other service really uses JSON-LD, compacting it to use the same context shouldn't be necessary'. Thanks for your patience, I am understanding a lot better.

Comment: forgot to ask about https://github.com/jsonld-java/jsonld-java, in the first line of the code example it says // Open a valid json(-ld) input file. Does that mean this will accept json on top of json-ld? This library sounds useful but cant tell if its for expanding/compacting already json-ld, or turning json into json ld.

Comment: @gallly, I have been trying to play around with jsonld-java-tool. However whenever I run `./jsonldplayground --inputFile myjson.json --process tordf`it doesn't give any output.
Can you kindly tell me if you were able to create jsonld from a json and the process for the same?